# Linq Expression Returns No Results with both Date and Int?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I have the following query (where NextDueDate is a nullable DateTime);

```
return context.Where<Job>(
       x =>
       x.NextDueDate != null &&
       x.NextDueDate >= from &&
       x.NextDueDate <= to).ToList();
```

returns 2 results (as expected) (I am looking for job that fall between a date range.)

I also have the second query (where StatusId is a nullable int);

```
return context.Where<Job>(
       x =>
       !x.StatusId.HasValue ||
       (x.StatusId != completeStatus.Id &&
        x.StatusId != cancelledStatus.Id)).ToList();
```

which again returns the results as expected as well. However, when I combine the 2 queries. Both the entries returned in this case have Status.Id == null;

```
return context.Where<Job>(
       x =>
       x.NextDueDate != null &&
       x.NextDueDate >= from &&
       x.NextDueDate <= to &&
       (!x.StatusId.HasValue ||
       (x.StatusId != completeStatus.Id &&
       x.StatusId != cancelledStatus.Id))).ToList();
```

I get 0 results when I am expecting 2 results from the database. What is the issue with my code above please. I basically want to return results that fall between my time period and are have StatusId == null or NOT the two arbitary ints.

I have output the generated SQL by EF which is;

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[NextDueDate] AS [NextDueDate], 
    [Extent1].[StatusId] AS [StatusId]
    FROM [dbo].[Jobs] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE ([Extent1].[NextDueDate] IS NOT NULL) 
    AND ([Extent1].[NextDueDate] >= @p__linq__0) 
    AND ([Extent1].[NextDueDate] <= @p__linq__1) 
    AND ([Extent1].[StatusId] <> @p__linq__2) 
    AND ([Extent1].[StatusId] <> @p__linq__3)


-- p__linq__0: '01/01/2018 00:00:00' (Type = DateTime2)

-- p__linq__1: '31/01/2018 00:00:00' (Type = DateTime2)

-- p__linq__2: '13' (Type = Int32, IsNullable = false)

-- p__linq__3: '37' (Type = Int32, IsNullable = false)

-- Executing at 13/02/2018 15:47:23 +00:00

-- Completed in 92 ms with result: SqlDataReader
```

Now I cannot understand why its returning nothing as there are 2 rows in the database which satisfy the query (for some reason the linq generated SQL seems to be stripping out the null check from the query?).

If I change the query as follows;

```
               return context.Where<Job>(
                    x =>
                    x.NextDueDate != null &&
                    x.NextDueDate >= from &&
                    x.NextDueDate <= to &&
                    (x.StatusId == null  ||
                    (!x.StatusId.Equals(completeStatus.Id )&&
                    !x.StatusId.Equals(cancelledStatus.Id)))).ToList();
```

I get the following exception;

> System.NotSupportedException: Unable to create a constant value of
>   type 'System.Object'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are
>   supported in this context.

Please see below a screenshot of my MSSQL query to show data does exist;

[image: MSSQL Screenshot]

**Nullable Int Check**

As Ruud pointed out the completeStatus.Id and cancelledStatus.Id are pulled from a second db query and are not nullable ints. After casting to an nullable int the following SQL is generated;

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[NextDueDate] AS [NextDueDate], 
    [Extent1].[StatusId] AS [StatusId]
    FROM [dbo].[Jobs] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE ([Extent1].[NextDueDate] IS NOT NULL) 
    AND ([Extent1].[NextDueDate] >= @p__linq__0) 
    AND ([Extent1].[NextDueDate] <= @p__linq__1) 
    AND ( NOT (([Extent1].[StatusId] = @p__linq__2) 
    AND (0 = (CASE WHEN (@p__linq__2 IS NULL) 
    THEN cast(1 as bit) ELSE cast(0 as bit) END)))) 
    AND ( NOT (([Extent1].[StatusId] = @p__linq__3) 
    AND (0 = (CASE WHEN (@p__linq__3 IS NULL) 
    THEN cast(1 as bit) ELSE cast(0 as bit) END))))


-- p__linq__0: '01/01/2018 00:00:00' (Type = DateTime2)

-- p__linq__1: '31/01/2018 00:00:00' (Type = DateTime2)

-- p__linq__2: '37' (Type = Int32)

-- p__linq__3: '13' (Type = Int32)

-- Executing at 13/02/2018 16:38:27 +00:00

-- Completed in 96 ms with result: SqlDataReader
```

However, still no results are being returned.

Comment: Just enable logging and see which SQL queries are generated, this will help you resolve the issue.

Comment: Please provide sample data so we can verify the results.

Comment: Are you sure you have data which satisfy above condition? because the code seems right

Comment: Please use a more detailed tag, for example [linq-to-sql] or [entity-framework].

Comment: Hi have enabled logging, added a screenshot and showed the data returned. It looks like the generated SQL is stripping out the null check on the StatusId?

Comment: The `!x.StatusId.HasValue` part isn't coming through, there's no `is null` part in the generated SQL. (Bug in EF?) Maybe an explicit `== null` works?

Comment: @Ruud I thought this but replacing x.StatusId == null gives the same sql generation. it seems to be stripping out he null check on the int values as its detailing IsNullable = false)

Comment: Just throwing some thoughts out there: are completeStatus.Id and cancelledStatus.Id nullable? If not, maybe the query optimizer thinks checking for null isn't necessary because of that. What happens if you compare `x.StatusId.Value` to those values instead of just `x.StatusId`?

Comment: they are pulled from another linq query, so you could be onto something there and yes the ID field will not be a nullable int. Let me try a cast on it.

Comment: @Ruud it does change the generated SQL now but still no results. I'll update the question to include the newly generated SQL.

Comment: Have you tried comparing the `Value` property of x.StatusId to those other IDs? That way you won't have to cast them to nullable types.

Comment: are you sure you are targeting the correct database? The generated query looks fine.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro pretty sure I have also tried the generated SQL in management studio and this returns no results either but the one I wrote does?

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this issue. What versions of .NET / EF / SQL Server are you using?

Comment: @MatthewFlynn in the query you wrote you qualified the database name though. Maybe you are targeting the correct instance, but not the correct database/schema?